# Avoid re-render component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 3 components:

- Parent
- Form
- Preview

With every change on Form Component, I pass the values to Parent, from Parent to Preview component. And it works.

The problem is when I change values on Form, the Preview component show like a flicker (because it's re-rendering the preview component). How can avoid this?

Maybe not updating preview component for every small change? How can I do it?

**Component diagram:**
[image: Here is components diagram]

Comment: Use `React.memo` on `Preview` component. It prevents component useless rendering when the next props equal to previous.

Comment: Can you add more code please? It's hard to help without knowing your components structure, state etc.

Comment: Hi @HarishSharma !  I did it..the thing is Preview has new values.. so memo doesn't help.. for example, I have 15 different values in the Form component, if one field value change, the Preview component re-render again